# Subspace of a bidual space of the space of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

My general question would be - how do I show that a certain space is a subspace of a topological bidual space?

More specific - if I have H as a locally compact Hausdorff space, and E as a locally convex topological vector space, and $C_0(H, E)$ is a space of continuous E-valued functions which vanish at $ \infty $, how would I show that a certain space is a subspace of the bidual space of $C_0(H, E)$? It is treated as obvious in my textbook, but I can't seem to connect the dots.

Comment: What is this "certain space"?

Comment: You have to be more specific, an example should help

Comment: This "certain space" is in my example a collection of E(locally convex topological space)-valued simple functions over the ring (D) consisting of Borel subsets of the locally compact Hausdorff space H. It was denoted as $S_E(D)$